# How to organize large CMakeList file

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm developing a cpp library and my CMakeList.txt starts to look like a big list of files. The library provides UI components so there is a lot of small classes, and UI related files. I find it hard to maintain as it hides logic and I wonder if there's something I can do.

I started making directories to regroup some files that are strongly connected to each other to make it clearer but it doesn't help the CMakeList. I consider two approaches:

1. Using file and GLOB but I read that's not recommended
2. Using "*.cmake" file in subfolders that will list files so I can keep the main CMakeLists.txt clean (or at least less overloaded).

To illustrate:

```
MyLibrary
│  CMakeLists.txt   ////< Big CMakeLists I want to split
│  filexxx.cpp
|  filexxx.h
│  more and more files
|  ...
└───Component
│   │   filexxx.cpp
│   │   filexxx.h
│   │   ...
└───SomeDialog
│   │   filexxx.cpp
│   │   filexxx.h
└───... ///< more directories
└───ui
│   │   someUiRelatedStuff.ui
│   │   someUiRelatedStuff.ui
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC
   filexxx.cpp
   Component/filexxx.cpp
   SomeDialog/filexxx.cpp
   # and so on for hundred of lines ...
)

# same goes for _HDR and _UI
```

All I could find was how to organize large project with multiple libraries or executables but not how to manage a big one. The closest question was : [How to write "CMakeLists.txt" for a big project with multiple subdirectories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162766/how-to-write-cmakelists-txt-for-a-big-project-with-multiple-subdirectories) but it's not really helping.

Comment: I put a `CMakeLists.txt` in each library or executable folder and one in the root level. So each `CMakeLists.txt` at most handles a single target.

Comment: Consider OBJECT libraries, built with a CMakeLists.txt in each subfolder.

Comment: There may be patterns you're able to exploit. You may be able to create a cmake function that allows you to do something like this `my_component(filexxx COMPONENT DIALOG)` or even just `my_component(filexxx)` if there is a large number of sources with corresponding files in the "root" dir, `Component` and `SomeDialog`...