# verifying my understanding of a CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

I successfully played trial-and-error with a `CMakeLists.txt` file, and now everything builds. However, I want to make sure my understanding is correct about how it's working.

I have a project with the following structure:

```
./
├── bin
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── sql-writer
│       ├── credentials.h
│       ├── database.h
│       ├── datetime.h
│       ├── market_bar.h
│       └── writer.h
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── database.cpp
│   ├── main.cpp
│   └── writer.cpp
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── test-main.cpp
    ├── test_sym_table_pairs
    └── writer_tests.cpp
```

This builds an executable, a static library, and a test executable. The problem was `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(HEADER_DIR ${sql-writer_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sql-writer)

add_executable(sql-writer-demo main.cpp ${HEADER_DIR})
target_include_directories(sql-writer-demo PUBLIC ${HEADER_DIR}) #!
target_link_libraries(sql-writer-demo sql-writer-lib mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

file(GLOB SOURCES ${sql-writer_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
file(GLOB HEADERS ${HEADER_DIR}/*.h)
add_library(sql-writer-lib ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(sql-writer-lib mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(sql-writer-lib PUBLIC ${HEADER_DIR})
```

1. the first line's `set` command just defines `HEADER_DIR`. This is easy.
2. `target_include_directories(sql-writer-demo PUBLIC ${HEADER_DIR})` must be included **after** the first `add_execuable` because otherwise header files will need to be included with relative paths. Is that right? Why does it come after? I've heard cmake treats include directories as "separate" from "sources" (cmake sources not .cpp files). What does that mean?
3. `target_link_libraries(sql-writer-demo sql-writer-lib mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` needs to come after `add_executable(sql-writer-demo main.cpp ${HEADER_DIR})` as well, and it tells how to link to other libraries.
4. `file(GLOB SOURCES ${sql-writer_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)` is not recomended before **only** because the directory/file structure could change, and then this wouldn't work anymore
5. `target_link_libraries(sql-writer-lib mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES})` needs to come after `add_library(sql-writer-lib ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})` because the compulation of my library `sql-writer-lib` needs to use other libs, and this is where we tell cmake to look out for those.

Comment: **Too many questions** in the single question post. Please, concentrate on a single question, and make sure you perform a search before the asking. `target_*` commands operates on the **target** passed as the first argument. So these commands should come after the target is defined,

Comment: @Tsyvarev It would not make sense to ask this into separate questions with the same context. The OP sounds good to me.

Comment: @Soleil: The context is quite small, so it is not a reason to not ask the separate questions. Moreover, for some questions the context can be reduced further, either by the author or by the editors who knows the area well. Understanding of include directories is quite a large topic, so there is no need to mix it with libraries linking. If the point 4 is a question, then it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil. Why should we **repeat** these answers again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You typically don't include headers into `add_executable` and `add_library`, but only implementation files:

  ```
  add_executable(sql-writer-demo main.cpp)
  add_library(sql-writer-lib ${SOURCES})
  ```
- `add_executable` and `add_library` create a target, `target_include_directories` specifies include directories for this target. The [documentation is pretty clear](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html):

  > The named `<target>` must **have been created** by a command such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()` and must not be an `IMPORTED` target.
- If you use `target_include_directories(sql-writer-lib PUBLIC ${HEADER_DIR})` with `PUBLIC` specifier, you don't need to use `target_include_directories` to specify include directories for targets that link against that library, because the dependency will be propagated automatically. The same applies to `target_link_libraries`.

So, `src/CMakeLists.txt`

```
file(GLOB SOURCES ${sql-writer_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)
add_library(sql-writer-lib ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(sql-writer-lib PUBLIC mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(sql-writer-lib PUBLIC ${HEADER_DIR})

add_executable(sql-writer-demo main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sql-writer-demo sql-writer-lib)
```

should work. Whether you want to use `PUBLIC` on `mysqlcppconn ${Boost_LIBRARIES}` depends on the structure of your project. I specified it as an example only.