# CMake file glob is evil?

Tags: c++, cmake

According to [Why is cmake file GLOB evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil), using glob as a target sources is a bad practice. I've tried to produce the described situation.

CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(main "${SOURCES}")
```

src/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I am running `cmake` once. After that I am creating an invalid cpp file src/test.cpp and running `cmake` once more, followed by `make`. According to situation described in the post I've to get everything compiled because cmake doesn't track this file. But in reality cmake does detect a change and compilation fails. Did I understand it wrong? I am using cmake version `3.17.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the post that you quoted, they don't run cmake after your new file creation.

They only run `make` and the `make` rule of Makefile generated by `CMake` should re-run `CMake` if the cache is outdated.

But in this case `CMake` doesn't detect the outdated cache and do not relaunch `CMake` to include your `test.cpp`.