# Why is a new file added in visual studio cmake project a miscellaneous files?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2022, cmakelists-options, cmake-language

Part of teh CMakeLists.txt are as followed:

```
add_library(pslite)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE "src/*.cc")
target_include_directories(pslite PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/")
target_sources(pslite PRIVATE ${SOURCE})
```

I am using vs2022 to develop this cmake project. From the cmake syntax above, the source and header files will be added to the `pslite` project. vs2022 does indeed recognize source files in the `src` directory.

However, when I added a new header file inside the `include` folder, vs2022 recognized that header file as miscellaneous and not in pslite's project, which prevented me from accurately locating things like the definition of the code.

Another interesting point is that the header files in the `src` directory are recognized, but the new header files are not. Why?

I tried to import the header file directly in CMakeLists.txt, like this:

```
target_sources(psquic PRIVATE ${SOURCE} "src/test.h")
```

Although the `test.h` header appears in the `src` directory of the `pslite` library in the cmake project view, it is still a miscellaneous file.

Comment: BTW, [why is CMake file GLOB evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil). And why do you expect to see changes in target `pslite` when changing `psquic`?

Comment: sorry, psquic is my misspelling in describing the problem, it's actually pslite.

Comment: How exactly are you using CMake with vs? "Open CMake folder" or `cmake -S ... -B ... && cmake --open ...`? Referring to the later case here: Adding the header file to the sources should work. Sometimes VS doesn't refresh everything properly. Check, if forcing a cmake configuration run and reopening the VS solution works: Select the solution in the solution explorer and use the context menu `Open in terminal`. Execute `cmake .`, close the solution in VS and reopen it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I find the reason why headers are shown as miscellaneous fileS in VS2022. The headers are actually copied into the source file at the location of `#include "[name].h"` and do not participate in compilation themselves.

The header in my project has not been included by any of the source files yet, so `vs2022` recognizes that head file as a miscellaneous file.

In fact, `CMakeList` doesn't need to use the `target_source` command to add headers to `target`. It just needs to provide a correct header address for the source file using the `target_include_directories` command.